What changes in Latex query can be made so that Our result is same as Image

%-----------EDUCATION & COURSES-----------
\section{Education}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
\resumeSubheading
    {State University}{Sep. 2017 -- May 2021}
    {Bachelor of Science in Chemical Engineering}{Medford, MA}


\resumeSubheading
{Relevant Courses} \\
Physical Chemistry of Polymers, Hazardous Waste Treatment Technology, Chemical and Biological Separations, Surface and Colloid Chemistry, Reactor Design, Data Structures
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd


Welcome! Please give the complete code from \documentclass to \end{document}. And if the document class you employ is not part of the TeX distribution, it's necessary to also provide the .cls file.

Commands as \resumeSubheading are not commands of standard classes, so improbably someone can guess in what class,  package or custom macro of some unknown  template  they were defined. But even if someone knows where these commands come from, not being able to compile the code as is and having to rebuild the document to test the solution is a pain and they probably won't bother to answer.
